# How to execute TipTap commands from script tag in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, rich-text-editor, tiptap

I'm having following component:

```
<button @click="$refs.image.click(); editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: state.image }).run()"></button>

<input type="file" ref="image" style="display: none" @change="getImageUrl">
```

The `button` uses the `file input` to access its upload image ui. Problem is that `getImageUrl` is an `async` function and:

```
editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: state.image }).run()
```

gets executed before `state.image` is set resulting in an undefined `img src`.

My approach is to put:

```
editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: state.image }).run()
```

inside its own `async function` but how do I call the chain command from `vue 3's` `script tag`? The [docs](https://tiptap.dev/api/commands) do not seem to explain how to call it from outside of `vue directives`.

**`getImageUrl`**:

```
const getImageUrl = (event) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        state.image = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. In the DOM element do:

```
<button @click="customCommand(editor)">push me</button>
```

and in `script setup`:

```
const customCommand = (editor) => {
    editor.commands.toggleBold()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap editor in ref to get access to editor commands from `<script>` section of component.

```js
const editor = ref(
  useEditor({
    content: "<p>I’m running Tiptap with Vue.js. </p>",
    extensions: [StarterKit],
  })
);

function setParagraph() {
   editor.value.chain().focus().setParagraph().run();
}
```